# Scrapy Selenium geckodriver problem - error while trying to scrape

Tags: selenium, scrapy

```
Unhandled error in Deferred: 2020-07-24 09:12:40 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 192, in crawl return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
_inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- --- File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks result = g.send(result) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl self.engine = self._create_engine() File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop()) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in init self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/init.py", line 83, in init self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 150, in create_instance instance = objcls.from_crawler(crawler,
*args, **kwargs) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py", line 67, in from_crawler middleware = cls( File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py", line 43, in init for argument in driver_arguments: builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

2020-07-24 09:12:40 [twisted] CRITICAL: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks result = g.send(result) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl self.engine = self._create_engine() File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop()) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in init self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/init.py", line 83, in init self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 150, in create_instance instance = objcls.from_crawler(crawler,
*args, **kwargs) File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py", line 67, in from_crawler middleware = cls( File "/home/baku/Dev/workspace/moje-python/scrape_linkedin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py", line 43, in init for argument in driver_arguments: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

my settings.py

from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')
SELENIUM_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('firefox')
...
'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800,
```

looks like permissions for driver are good:

> :/usr/local/bin$ ll | grep gecko
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 baku baku 7008696 lip 24 09:09 geckodriver*

crawler code:

```
class LinkedInProfileSeleniumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lips'
    allowed_domains = ['www.linkedin.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url="https://www.linkedin.com/login/",
            callback=self.proceed_login,
            wait_until=(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#username")
                    )
            ),
            script='window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);',
            wait_time=30
        )

    def proceed_login(self, response):
        # AFTER LOGIN
        driver = response.request.meta['driver']
        ...
```

can you please help why it's failing? thanks!

( btw it works with chrome drivers, fails with gecko )
The same problem I had on mac, this one I am trying on ubuntu machine.
Not sure what can be the issue, there to debug etc.
I does not even land into self.proceed_login. Fails on first request.

Comment: You're going to have to show abit more code for us to help you. All I know is that you're using scrapy_selenium and you have problem with the extracted data which is giving a NoneType. It would also be preferable if you put the trackback in a coding block rather than blockquote, it's quite jarring to look at!

Comment: @AaronS ok added crawler code :)